# Redirected to private route before Firebase onAuthStateChanged populate state lead to sign in page again

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

When signin in, the redirect is faster than the state update from `onAuthStateChanged()`. How do you handle that behaviour?

```js
// firebase/index.js
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default app

export const FirebaseContext = createContext({})
export const FirebaseProvider = FirebaseContext.Provider
```

```js
// index.js

import firebase, { FirebaseProvider } from './firebase'

            <FirebaseProvider value={firebase}>
                <App />
            </FirebaseProvider>
```

```js
// App.js

const App = () => {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ loading: true, user: null })

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            console.log(user)
            if (user) {
                console.log("logged in")
                setAuth({ loading: false, user })
            } else {
                console.log("not logged in")
                setAuth({ ...auth, loading: false })
            }
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            ...

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
                    <Route exact path="/signout" component={SignOut} />
                    <Route exact path="/public" component={Public} />
                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/private" auth={auth} comp={Private} />
```

```js
// signin.js

import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { FirebaseContext } from '../firebase'

const SignIn = ({ history }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({})
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false)

    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)

    const signIn = () => {
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(state.email, state.password)
            .then(() => {
                history.push("/private")
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                ...
            })
    }

    return (
        ...
    )
}

export default withRouter(SignIn)
```

```js
// PrivateRoute.js

const PrivateRoute = ({ auth, comp: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => 
                auth.loading
                    ? <Loading on={true} />
                    : !!auth.user
                        ? <Component {...props} />
                        : <Redirect to={"/signin"} />
            }
        />
    )
}
```

When I sign in successfully (no error message, and network `getAccountInfo` is responding with user info), the `history.push` is redirecting but the `PrivateRoute` redirect me to `/signin` again instead of the `/private` route. If I change the URL manually and load the `/private` route, I'm logged in.

This is the console:

```
// go to /private when not logged in -> redirected to /signin = OK

App.js: null
App.js: not logged in
PrivateRoute.js: {loading: false, user: null}

// on /signin page, fill form and submit

PrivateRoute.js: {loading: false, user: null}
App.js: P {N: Array(0), l: ... }
App.js: logged in

// go to /private by typing it in the browser

PrivateRoute.js: {loading: true, user: null}
App.js: P {N: Array(0), l: ... }
App.js: logged in
PrivateRoute.js: {loading: false, user: P { ... }} <-- the /private page is now rendered
```

I understand that when signing in successfully, I'm redirected before the `onAuthStateChanged()` has the time to populate the `auth` state.

How should I handle this? I tried a lot of solution with no success :(

Comment: have you tried to prevent redirection to sign in page on loading state?

Comment: Yes but I'm stuck in the same situation than the PrivateRoute where loading is false.. Or perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

useEffect will always run after first render, so you will always be get caught on logout state which leads fast redirection between login and private page. You should keep user authentication data on localStorage and use it right away before render (not set it on useEffect); so that if user already authenticated you won't need to fetch this data every visit.

```js
const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ loading: true, user: localStorage.getItem('user')})
```

You also need to clean localStorage after logout or failed authentication to prevent miss redirections.